# R Remove whitespace between chart area and axes

Tags: r, plot

I have just made a simple time series plot of the FTSE and some moving averages.

1. Does anyone know of the correct way to remove the whitespace between the bottom of my graph and the x-axis.
2. The trendlines drop out of the chart area region into the whitespace, how can I fix this?
3. How can I add the y axis line on the left of the plot (as in a vertical line going up from 02-Jan-07

Apologies if these are trivial questions and thanks in advance.

[Graph in Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDopJ.jpg)

My Code:

```
ftse = read.csv("data.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
ftse.ts = xts(ftse[,-1], order.by = as.Date(ftse$Date , format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
ftse = ftse.ts[, "FTSE.Close"]
names(ftse) = "FTSE100"
fastMA.ftse = rollapply(data = ftse[!is.na(ftse)], width = 50, FUN = mean)
slowMA.ftse = rollapply(data = ftse[!is.na(ftse)], width = 200, FUN = mean)

par(mfrow = c(1,1),family="serif")
plot(ftse,col="dark blue", lwd=1)
lines(slowMA.ftse,col="red",lty=2)
lines(fastMA.ftse,col="orange",lty=2)
```

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example i.e. example data and your code.

Comment: Added my code to post. first few lines of csv data as follows:
"Date","FTSE.Open","FTSE.High","FTSE.Low","FTSE.Close","FTSE.Volume","FTSE.Adjusted"
2007-01-02,6220.799805,6312.5,6220.799805,6310.899902,1074946500,6310.899902
2007-01-03,6310.899902,6322,6296,6319,1606892700,6319
2007-01-04,6319,6319,6261,6287,1902875500,6287
2007-01-05,6287,6287,6220.100098,6220.100098,1622439300,6220.100098
2007-01-08,6220.100098,6246,6187,6194.200195,1326700900,6194.200195
2007-01-09,6194.200195,6218.5,6190.399902,6196.100098,2143699600,6196.100098